# R-making a correlation table

Tags: r, correlation

I have a data frame with multiple fields. I'd like to compute pearson correlation of each pair of files and store it in a table.
input:

```
H1 H2 H3
1  2  3
5  4  8
...
```

output:

```
    H1              H2           H3
H1  1             cor(H1,H2)    cor(H1,H3)
H2 cor(H1,H2)        1          cor(H2,H3)
H3 cor(H1,H3)     cor(H1,H3)      1
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can just call `cor` on your table like:

```
cor(dataframe)
```